# Grails 3 Container Managed Authentication

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails3

I am trying to upgrade my existing grails application from version 2.5.6 to 3.3.11.

So far, container managed application was configured in the application via web.xml, with `<login-config>`. Here is the configuration:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login/login</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login/login_error</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

As grails 3 has stopped supporting `web.xml` file, I am wondering how to maintain Container Managed Authentication. The reason for using Container Managed Authentication (CMA) is that our application doesn't want to handle the authentication process, as different customers have different authentication mechanisms at their end. So we prefer CMA.

Have read many online forums, they all end up with Spring Security plugin. But didn't find a configuration with Spring Security which gives control of authentication to the container.

So, how to configure CMA with Grails 3?